# Moving classes and changing namespace. Classes not checked into TFS

Tags: tfs

Using TFS in Visual Studio 2010.

Has anyone noticed that if you move a class from one folder to another folder using Solution Explorer (also changing the namespace), then check-in your changes that:

- original class file is correctly removed
- new class file (the moved one) is not added to source control

No warning is given. Only when some one else checks out the project is it realised that something is missing. TFS Source Control Explorer acts as if the file is checked in.

The only way I can get around this is to go into Windows Explorer and manually add each class that has been moved using TFS power tools. Then checking in again.

I have had this problem about 5 times now.

Is this how TFS is intended to work or is it a bug? Or is it only me and I am doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you moving the File? Source Control Explorer, or Solution Explorer?

Comment: When I do a "move" in Solution Explorer it is a "Copy", this performs an "Add" at the new Location and edits the destination project. Do you have all Service Packs and updates installed (http://tinyurl.com/7xueeys)?

Comment: When I was doing the move, I was dragging and dropping files or using 'cut'. I installed that useful extension, cheers. It recommends a  [minor update version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082). Trying that now.

Comment: I've just done a major refactor and required a lot of files moving. I used Source Control Explorer to perform every "Move" and then Solution Explorer to Add them into and Remove them from the Projects. It was slow, but because it was a "Move" the history came with the file.

Comment: Excellent, with that update it all appears to be working correctly now thanks.

Comment: Copied my comment to an answer.

Comment: Wrong comment copied, it was the one with the update that solved it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have all Visual Studio Updates installed.

If the TFS Server version is ahead of your Visual Studio version you can encounter these weird problems.

There's a free (albeit slightly snarky) extension to VS2010 that let's you know which updates you're missing called [VersionInfo](http://tinyurl.com/7xueeys).

Comment: Did this fix your problem? TFS is not meant to behave this way and it sounds like a bug in the project system.  If this is still broken, what type of project (C#, VB, etc.) are you doing these operations in?